# Ler Html de uma pagina web executando uma aplicação em wpf c#

Tags: c#

Boa noite,

Estou com uma tarefa de conseguir criar uma aplicação desktop para ler o HTML de uma pagina. Com algumas pesquisas consegui criar um método que faz a leitura do HTML e me retorna uma string, segue o código:

```
string strSiteUrl = "URL";

request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSiteUrl);
response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
stream = response.GetResponseStream();
streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
pereira.txbDescricaoPagina.Text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

O meu problema é que a página que preciso ler é carregada dinamicamente via javascript, ou seja, o HTML é injetado dinamicamente na página e o meu método não consegue enxergar o HTML.

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda.

Comment: você tem que adicionar um WebBrowser, e esperar a página ser carregada

Comment: Oi Rovann, poderia me explicar com mais detalhes, como eu usaria o WebBroser dentro de uma aplicação descktop?

Comment: o @JoaoMartins respondeu, é basicamente isso... só que ainda após o DocumentCompleted, é necessário aguardar o javascript carregar tudo... nesse caso, um timer e uma verificação do conteúdo pra saber se está pronto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acrescente ao seu `Form` um controlo do tipo `WebBrowser` (ou crie em código mesmo), onde depois, em código, deve evocar o método `Navigate` para navegar para o URL que pretende:

```
WebBrowser webBrowser1 = new WebBrowser();

webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http:\\www.google.com");
```

Por fim, no evento `DocumentCompleted` pegue o que precisa:

```
private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    WebBrowser wb = sender as WebBrowser;

    // obtém todo o HTML do corpo para uma "string"
    string body = wb.Document.Body.InnerHtml;

    // percorre todos os elementos HTML no documento
    foreach (HtmlElement elemento in wb.Document.All)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Não se esqueça de dar também um UP na resposta :)

Comment: Fala João Martins,

Realizei um teste aqui como sugerido e funcionou, ele esperou o javascript terminar de injetar o html para depois ler.

Mas acontece o meu caso exige um pouco mais de atenção, o método sugerido acima esperou o carregamento todo da pagina, mas o javascript não só injetou HTML mas também outras chamadas de script que o meto acima não esperou desses métodos.

Vou ler mais sobre WebBrowser para aprender mais sobre este objeto mas caso você tenha uma sugestão sobre esta segunda questão e quiser comentar eu ficaria muito agradecido.

Valeu.